# Changing javascript method contents gives “Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined” error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can we change the HTML of a document during the button click event or document load event? I am seeking to change the contents of a javascript function which is located inside a script tag. When I do an HTML. replace it gives me Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined error.

```
$(this).html(function (i, html) {
    console.log($(this).html);
    return html.replace('window.parent.SysCloseModalPopup', 'window.parent.O365CloseModalPopup')
});
```

My JSfiddle example is located https://jsfiddle.net/codecrasher99/fpqngt4h/9/

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way to do what you are trying to do, rewriting JS code on button click sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: First of all: What do you want to achieve? Do you really want to change the contents of a function or, as your code sample suggests, do you want to do something else, like changing the background color of a modal window?

Comment: have you tried the code outside of jsfiddle? It seems the error is from jsfiddle's own code rather than yours, though I'm not 100% sure

Comment: When my document is loaded I want to change all instances of window.parent.SysCloseModalPopup with window.parent.O365CloseModalPopup

Comment: @alex The code gives an error even outside JSFiddle

Comment: why don't you rather put the code in an ``if-construct`` to check whether the document is loaded or not? That seems more handy than replacing the code.

Comment: @alex Moving the function call to a document load event also gives the same error.

Comment: there is no property .html of $(this) element, that why you are getting error at line number 77 i.e $(this).html(function (i, html)   at onDocumentLoaded ((index):77)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [javascript Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) object to modify the existing function

```
    var funccontents = OldFunction.toString(); 
funccontents = funccontents.replace('window.parent.SysCloseModalPopup', 'window.parent.O365CloseModalPopup'); 
// Replace the original function 
OldFunction = new Function(funccontents.substring(funccontents.indexOf('{') + 1, funccontents.lastIndexOf('}')));
```